# How to run a simple Whisper (SHH) example

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, whisper

I am struggling to get a simple whisper (shh) example running.
I am using the following versions:
geth 1.9.24-stable-cc05b050
web3 6.14.5

I am running geth with the following command:

```
geth --shh --rpc
```

And I start coding with the following linex:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
var shh = web3.shh;
(async function main() {
   var keyPair = await shh.newKeyPair();
})();
```

Then I get the following error:

```
Error: Returned error: the method shh_newKeyPair does not exist/is not available
```

I guess that the shh command is not supported by the node (geth).

Can anyone instruct how to get a simple message passing example using Whisper running with the versions above? Thanks for the support.

Comment: Have you enabled shh api? something like `geth --shh --http --http.api shh`. The old parameters `rpc` `rpcapi` were deprecated, https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options.

Answer (score 0):

v1.9.24 no longer has whisper, it has been trashed since v1.9.21.
You should use a previous version. (like v1.9.17)

Comment: Why was whisper trashed? What is the alternative p2p?